# vpc/mlag block half of uplink?

Tags: vpc, port-channel, arista

We want to configure 2 Arista switches by mlag and connect 1 port channeled switch to both of arista's. so in this case, if one of our arista fail the other one will respond.
now my question here is in this scheme one of the arista block packets from receiving and only one of them is working, right? and if that working unit fails my traffic travel through second arista and second one will be elect as primary ?

in another word my traffic will not travel through both arista and towards my routers?

Thank you.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

The whole point of MLAG / VPC is to have both link active, as in a standard link aggregation. Otherwise there would be little benefit over xSTP (spanning tree) (yes it converges faster but it's much more complex to setup and not interoperable between different brands).

So if properly configured:

- when all links are up, you got the full bandwidth
- when a link is down, both switches continue to forward traffic. If needed the switch with the failed link will transfer the frames to the other switch and they will then be sent to the destination host.

Comment: so your mean is if i set one of them arista as primary and then one of my link from my downstream switch to arista 1 drop then second arista can not handle it ? in this case only this switch traffic should travel through arista 2 and other switch traffic travel from arista 1,  does not it?

Comment: MLAG has no concept of primary ports. As @JFL mentioned, all links are active.

Comment: You may want to read https://www.arista.com/en/products/multi-chassis-link-aggregation-mlag, where Arista explains their MLAG implementation in (a bit) more detail.

Comment: @Blackmetal edited to clarify

Comment: Understood, so all links are active and if any of links fail i will have link failover, am i right?

Comment: That's the idea with MLAG:  from the downstream device's perspective it's just a single channel with n active links.  A client switch connected to 4 ports across two switches in an MLAG is functionally no different than the same switch connected to a single switch with a 4-way channel.  That said, there are a ton of details about how upstream and downstream traffic is handled on the MLAG pair plus interaction with FHRP's, etc that should be carefully considered in the design.

Comment: actuallty our routers are using VRRP and our Arista switches using MLAG , so in any case if one of my links from downstream switch for Arista fail the second one will respond with no downtime, am i right?

Comment: Correct, there is no packetloss in a lacp trunk over mlag failover.

Comment: just one more things, when i execute show mlag in my arista switch one of them isprimary and one of them is secondary, why does it show this way if they are active-active?

Comment: @Blackmetal you can have a kind of "layer 3 MLAG" (not sure how it is called in Arista) which is basically VRRP over MLAG. This topology require a master (active) and slave (passive) device that handle the virtual IP. It is not relevant if you use only a layer 2 MLAG.

Comment: my arista switch only doing layer 2 and my layer  3 handle in my juniper mx40